# Does $e^Xe^Y = e^Ye^X$ iff $[X,Y]=0$ hold once we are sufficiently close to the identity of a Lie group?

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras

Let $G$ be a Lie group with Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}$. Must there exist a neighbourhood $U \subseteq \mathfrak{g}$ of $0$ such that, for all $X,Y \in U$, the implication
$$e^Xe^Y = e^Ye^X \Rightarrow [X,Y]=0$$
is valid?

I don't have any formal education in Lie groups and algebras, self-administered or otherwise, so, while I often have guesses as to what sorts of things should be true, I rarely know how to go about proving them. My only idea went something like this:

- Word on the street is that, locally, the product structure of Lie group can be described by analytic functions on the Lie algebra.
- We should be able to view $\{(X,Y): e^Xe^Y=e^Ye^X\}$ as the zero set of some analytic function.
- The zero set of a (multivariable) analytic function probably can't look that bad
- ....?

Comment: [I think so.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baker%E2%80%93Campbell%E2%80%93Hausdorff_formula)

Comment: @DanielFischer: I'm not sure I understand... So, let's say the BCH series for $Z(X,Y) = \log(e^Xe^Y)$ converges absolutely and uniformly in some neighbourhood of $X=Y=0$. So, we find the $X,Y$ with $e^Xe^Y = e^Ye^X$ as the zeros of $Z(X,Y) -Z(Y,X) = [X,Y] + (\text{3rd order terms and higher})$. Am I forgetting some basic thing about Taylor series? Let's say $g : \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ is a real analytic and of the form $g(x) = Q(x) +\epsilon(x)$ where $Q$ is a quadratic form and $\epsilon$ is $o(|x|^2)$. Can I automatically conclude that zeros of $g$ are also zeros of $Q$?

Comment: No, in general you cannot conclude that. But since the higher order terms are all commutators of (commutators of …) $X$ and $Y$, it's not obviously absurd to hope that for $X,Y$ close enough to $0$ with $[X,Y] \neq 0$, all the higher order terms add up to something smaller than $[X,Y]$. However, I don't know if that is indeed the case, and I have no idea how to prove or refute it. So it's just a guess.

Comment: @DanielFischer: OK thanks, I thought maybe you had a proof in mind when you wrote that comment
. Also, I guess I could have written $Z(X,Y) - Z(Y,X) =[X,Y] + (\text{4th order terms and higher})$, since it looks like the odd order terms of $Z(X,Y)$ and $Z(Y,X)$ are equal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it's true. Indeed, we can locally write the BCH formula as
$$\log(e^xe^y)=x+y+\frac12[x,y]+Q(x,y,[x,y]).$$
Here $Q$ is defined as follows: the remainder (sum of terms of order $\ge 3$ in BCH) is written as $\sum_i \lambda_iP_i(x,y)([x,y])$, where $P_i$ is some nonempty finite product of the operators $\mathrm{ad}(x)$ and $\mathrm{ad}(y)$, and $Q(x,y,z)=\sum \lambda_iP_i(x,y)(z)$. In particular we can bound around zero $\|Q(x,y,z)\|\le C\max(\|x\|,\|y\|)\|z\|$ for a suitable constant (and choice of norms).

If $e^xe^y=e^ye^x$ for small $x,y$, this yields
$$x+y+\frac12[x,y]+Q(x,y,[x,y])=y+x+\frac12[y,x]+Q(y,x,[y,x]),$$
that is,
$$[x,y]=Q(y,x,-[x,y])-Q(x,y,[x,y]).$$

This yields $\|[x,y]\|\le 2C\max(\|x\|,\|y\|)\|[x,y]\|$. If $[x,y]\neq 0$, this yields $1\le 2C\max(\|x\|,\|y\|)$, which is a contradiction if $(x,y)$ is too close to $(0,0)$.

Comment: Do you really $\leq C \max(\|x\|,\|y\|) \|z\|$ instead of something 3rd order, like $C \|x\|\|y|\|z\|$ or maybe $C (\max(\|x\|,\|y\|)^2 \|z\|$?

Comment: @MikeF I mean what I wrote. It's not 3rd order because $[x,y]$ is one of the variables. For instance, in the 3-nilpotent case, the remainder is a scalar multiple of $[x-y,[x,y]]$, so I mean $Q(x,y,z)=[x-y,z]$ in this case.

Answer (score 2):

It is enough to prove the result for $X$, $Y$  $n\times n$ complex matrices.

Now, we have the following formula:

$$e^X e^Y e^{-X}= \exp( Ad(e^X)(Y))$$ where

$$Ad(e^X)(Y) = \exp( ad(X)) (Y)$$  where again
the operator $ad(X)$ acts on $n\times n$ matrices by
$$Z \mapsto ad(X) Z \colon = [X,Z]$$ and $\exp ad(X)$ is the exponential of this linear map from $M_n(\mathbb{C})$ to itself.

Now we have to show that $\exp (T)(Y) = Y$ implies $T Y = 0$, if $T$ is small enough. In fact we have the following:

Let $T$ be a linear map on a finite dimensional (complex) vector space $V$ and $v$ in $V$ so that $\exp T v = v$. Assume moreover that  $T$ has no eigenvalues $\lambda = 2 k \pi i$, $k \ne 0$. Then $T v = 0$.  Hint: consider the Jordan canonical form of $T$.

$\bf{Added:}$ You can also show the last statement is true for $T$ small enough using the formula

$$\log ( I + ( e^T - I)) = T$$ where 
$$\log ( I + S) = S - \frac{S^2}{2} + \frac{S^3}{3} + \cdots$$

Comment: Perhaps the simplest way to see that $e^T v = v$ implies $T v = 0$ for $T$ small enough is to consider the equality $e^ T - I =  S \cdot T$ where $S = \sum_{n \ge 0} \frac{T^n}{(n+1)!}$. Now $S$ is an invertible operator if $T$ is small enough, in fact, if $T$ has no eigenvalues of form $2 k \pi i$, with $k \ne 0$.