# Upper bound for $\frac{2^n}{n!} \sum_{m=1}^n \frac{\#\{\text{surjections } [n] \to [m]\}}{m}$

Tags: combinatorics, power-series, lie-groups, estimation, upper-lower-bounds

In connection with [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2392568/does-exey-eyex-iff-x-y-0-hold-once-we-are-sufficiently-close-to-the), I would like to do some estimates using the Baker-Campbell-Hausdorff formula.

Let us define

$$a_n= \frac{2^n}{n!} \sum_{m=1}^n \frac{ \mathrm{Surj}(n,m)}{m}$$

where $\mathrm{Surj}(n,m)$ denotes the number of surjective maps from an $n$-element set to an $m$-element set. If one prefers, one may use $\mathrm{Surj}(n,m)=m! S(n,m)$, where $S(n,m)$ denotes the Stirling number of the second kind (i.e. the number of partitions of an $n$-element set into $m$ nonempty parts).

> **Question:** What kind of upper bounds for $a_n$ can we come up with? Can we prove that the power series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n x^n$ has a positive radius of convergence?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let us see... as correctly stated by the OP, $\text{Surj}(n,m)=m!{n\brace m}=\sum_{j=0}^{m}(-1)^{m-j}\binom{m}{j}j^n$, hence:

$$ a_n = \frac{2^n}{n!}\sum_{m=1}^{n}\Gamma(m){n\brace m}=\frac{2^n}{n!}\int_{0}^{+\infty}\sum_{m=1}^{n}\lambda^m{n \brace m}\frac{d\lambda}{\lambda e^{\lambda}}$$
equals:
$$ a_n=\frac{2^n}{n!}\int_{0}^{+\infty}\mathbb{E}[X_{\mu=\lambda}^n]\frac{d\lambda}{\lambda e^{\lambda}}=\frac{2^n}{n!}\int_{0}^{+\infty}\sum_{k\geq 0}\frac{\lambda^k e^{-\lambda}k^n}{k!}\cdot\frac{d\lambda}{\lambda e^{\lambda}}\,d\lambda $$
where $X_{\mu=\lambda}$ [is a Poisson random variable with expected value $\lambda$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind#Moments_of_the_Poisson_distribution). By switching $\int$ and $\sum$ we get:

$$ a_n = \frac{2^n}{n!}\sum_{k\geq 0}\frac{k^{n-1}}{2^k}\approx\frac{2^n}{n!}\int_{0}^{+\infty}k^{n-1}2^{-k}\,dk=\frac{1}{n}\left(\frac{2}{\log 2}\right)^n $$
hence the radius of convergence of $\sum_{n\geq 0}a_n x^n$ is positive but finite, around $\frac{\log 2}{2}\approx \frac{1}{3}$.

Comment: Wow! I feel very fortunate to have gotten such a wonderful response to my rather unmotivated question. Out of curiosity, is their some reason why you choose to write $\frac{d \lambda}{\lambda e^{\lambda}}$ in your calculations? Is this somehow a natural measure?

Comment: @MikeF: a natural measure for this particular problem, for sure. We know that there is a nice closed expression for $\sum \lambda^m{n \brace m}$, so we just need to turn a $\lambda^m$ into a $\Gamma(m)$, and the operator $$ f(\lambda) \mapsto \int_{0}^{+\infty}f(\lambda)\frac{d\lambda}{\lambda e^{\lambda}} $$ does exactly such job.

Comment: I just noticed $\log(2)/2$ shows up on the wikipedia page for the Baker-Campbell-Hausdorff formula [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baker%E2%80%93Campbell%E2%80%93Hausdorff_formula#Questions_of_convergence). That seems unlikely to be a coincidence! :)

Comment: @MikeF: definitely not a coincidence, it means that the above $\approx$ is accurate enough to lead to the actual radius of convergence, not just something close.